# CircleCI 2.0 Android Espresso No config found and No Tests Errors

Tags: android, circleci-2.0

Upon deploying my App with Espresso tests on CircleCI I get "No configuration" and "No Tests" error. The Espresso tests are working fine locally on Android Studio.

1. With a commit, CI job runs and fails with "No config found" error. details of the error is as follows:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
   #No configuration was found in your project. Please refer to https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ to get started with your configuration.
   false
   Exited with code 1
   ```
2. When I manually setup and build the project on Circle-CI I see it's progressing from Starting the build--> Start Container -->Enable SSH -->Restore source cache --> Checkout using deploy key xxx till Disable SSH, and then it shows "NO TESTS"  Error.

Below is my `.circleci/config.yml`

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      # Android the primary container
      - image: circleci/android:api-26-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Setup emulator
          command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;default;armeabi-v7a" && echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-16;default;armeabi-v7a"
      - run:
          name: Launch emulator
          command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib && emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel auto -verbose
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Wait emulator
          command: |
            # wait for it to have booted
            circle-android wait-for-boot
            # unlock the emulator screen
            sleep 30
            adb shell input keyevent 82
      - run:
          name: Run EspressoTests
          command: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
```

My app's SDK details are:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 27
```

I tried changing Docker image version to api-25-alfa and api-27-alfa as well. I am new to CircleCI.

I have [cross-posted this to the CircleCI discussion forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/circleci-2-0-android-espresso-no-config-found-and-no-tests-errors/25075).

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to cross-post to many channels at the same time, since it may be seen as a "drive by" request to communities that you do not wish to be a part of. However, if you must do this, it is good practice to declare that you have done so, by linking to each copy, in order not to waste the time of people who may spend time creating a duplicate answer.

Comment: Thanks for educating a good practice. After spending several hours in figuring out the problem, when i could not hit a solution then posted this on Circle CI as it is a circle ci related problem and also here on stack overflow to seek help from a bigger forum. But, agree i should have mentioned this in my posts.

Comment: for this line : command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib && emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel auto -verbose  I have emulator64-arm command not found, do you know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The git hub repo which was mapped to Circle CI was one level up the actual project directory containing `.circleci/config.yml`. Looks like this was the reason my config was not getting found by Circle CI. I created a new repo, committed contents of the project to it including `.circleci`, added this to Circle CI and both issues got resolved.